# CSS changes shows up in eclipse but not on browser

Tags: html, css, eclipse, web, directory

I have an index.html file and index.css. The directory structure is:
[img of directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGNua.png)

I am linking the css to html with :  `link rel="stylesheet" type="text.css" href="css/index.css"`

I am using tomcat v8.5 to host. When I run my project on server I see this in the window within eclipse:
[browser displayed within eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoIUo.png)

However when I open up chrome/firefox and search, it is only pulling the index.html and the css is not being displayed :(

I read that files have to be specified with "relative path", however, the folder containing index.css is in the same directory(WebContent) as the index.html. So what is the issue with href="css/index.css" ? Can someone please help me with the path issue?

Thanks so much for your time !

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight mistake in the link tag. Replace type="text.css" with type="text/css":

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
```

Comment: Okay so the "type=" specifies that the link is a text document that, in this case, contains css. Please correct me if I am wrong here. If not, thanks for your time! :)